# warnings when activating the optimization options

Tags: c, linux, gcc, scanf

I use scanf in a c program to read an int from STDIN:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

when I compile the c program with optimization enabled I get some warnings:

```
gcc main.c -lm -lpthread -O2 -o main
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:45: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
main.c:50: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
```

but when I remove the optimization options, why don't I get those warnings?

```
gcc main.c -lm -lpthread -o main
```

P.S: I'm not using -Wall or something similar.

Comment: Posting more codes will help us to analysis your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changing optimizer settings changes how much (and how) the compiler analyzes your code.

Some program flow analysis is not done when optimization is not enabled (or not set high enough), so the related warnings are not issued.
You'll see that frequently for "unused variable" warnings - these require analysis of the code beyond what is necessary to simply compile it, so you'll ususally only get them with optimization enabled.

(And you really should be compiling with `-Wall`.)

Comment: You can look at the `-Wuninitialized` documentation (in the man page), for instance: "Because these warnings depend on
           optimization, the exact variables or elements for which there are warnings will depend on the
           precise optimization options and version of GCC used."

Answer (score 3):

`-Wunused-result` is [enabled by default](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno_002dunused_002dparameter-331): Because you'll actively need to decorate a function with `__attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))` to trigger the warning, false positives only occur when it's used too liberally.

Even without passing additional flags, gcc *should* produce a warning. However, as Mat explained, the compiler doesn't do the necessary control flow analysis without increasing optimization levels.

Fix your code or silence the warning by adding `-Wno-unused-result`. <del>Casting the return value to `void` will probably do as well.</del>

To silence the warning in code, you'll need to assign the return value to a dummy variable, which you then can cast to `void` to avoid a new warning about the unused variable. It's also possible to substitute a C99 compound literal for the explicitly declared variable (tested with gcc 4.5.3).

This is indeed not optimal - I really expected the `void`-cast I originally porposed to work...

Comment: @obounaim: I don't know if it is, but a quick online search shows that bugs related to this (eg http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43361 ) are marked WONTFIX

Comment: There are actually plenty of false positives, and `scanf` is one of them. These are regularly reported on the glibc bugzilla, and some of them get fixed. For example, it's possible to use `scanf`-family functions entirely safely without checking the return value as long as you have another way of determining if it read all the values, or if you pre-fill the variables to be read with default values that can be used when there's no suitable input.

Comment: @R..: I stand corrected; also, the cast to `void` doesn't quiet the warning on my gcc 4.5.3, which is unexpected...

Comment: @R.. This may be right for `sscanf`, but `scanf` reads from stdin and nobody should make any assumption about what gets read from it. Not checking the result from `scanf` is a sin. Always.

Comment: @R.. (void) don't quiet the warning on my gcc 4.4.3 too

Comment: @Jens: That's false. `int x, n=-1; scanf("%d%n", &x, &n); if (n<0) ...` is perfectly acceptable and does not use the return value.

Comment: @R..I consider that another form of testing a return value. We can split hair on this. The point is that using a variable after an unchecked scanf is unsafe at best; the newbies here should be taught hard and fast rules until they are masters who know when breaking the rules is okay.